# Simple percentage calculation

Tags: percentages

This is an easy question, but since I grew dumb in the years, I ask for your help! :)

A = 50%
B = 75%
C = 100%
D = 125%
E = 150%

How can I calculate the value of any of these letters? I'm making a dopesheet and the more I think the more confused I am.

Can have only 1 number. For example:
D is "x". Calculate A,B,C,E.
Etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to obtain value of 1% namely if D is x then we need to divide x by 125,then we can enlarge it as many times as we like be it 50 for 50% or 3 for 3%,that way you can calculate it